# Jquery image tooltip for some thumbnails

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a tooltip with in image in, that is shown when hovered on a smaller image (thumbnail)

This works:

```
<img alt='geen foto beschikbaar' class='plupic' id='Pic5' src='fotos/nopic.jpg' style="margin:10px; max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px;">
    <script>
    $(function() {
     $( document ).tooltip({
        items: "img",
        content: function() {
        var element = $( this );
        if ( element.is( "img" ) ) {
          var src = element.attr('src');
           return "<img src='" + src + "'>";
        }
      }
     });
    });
    </script>
```

But that creates a tooltip on every image on my site, that is not what I want, I want tooltips on some images, but not all.

This I tried, but does not work:

```
<img alt='geen foto beschikbaar' class='plupic' id='Pic5' src='fotos/nopic.jpg' style="margin:10px; max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px;">
    <script>
    $(function() {
     $('.plupic').tooltip({
        content: function() {
        var element = $( this );
        var src = element.attr('src');
        return "<img src='" + src + "'>";
      }
     });
    });
    </script>
```

It simply does nothing, not even a warning or error. What do I do wrong?

Comment: if your first .tooltip example works you can just use items: ".plupic",

Comment: Thanks this works! But why doesn't mine work?